# Análise espacial em R: como implementar um polígono com splancs?

Tags: r, polígono, análise-de-dados

Estou tentando calcular a intensidade de um padrão pontual com "kernel smooth" (desculpem, não sei como traduzir isso). Antes de executar o código do Kernel smooth, é preciso especificar uma largura de banda de histograma para seus dados. São possíveis várias larguras diferentes, e uma orientação comum é calcular a média dos erros quadrados ("Mean Squared Error", de agora em diante MSE) da distribuição e usar o menor valor no início.

Uma função do pacote `splancs` para calcular MSE é `mse2d()`, especificada com quatro argumentos:

```
mse2d(pts,poly,nsmse,range)
```

sendo `pts` a distribuição de pontos, `poly` um polígono que representa a área onde os pontos estão, `nsmse` é o número de das bandas do histograma para as quais se quer calcular MSE, e o `range` é o tamanho máximo de banda para o MSE.

Meu problema é o argumento `poly`. Como especificar o script para esse polígono? Não encontrei nenhuma orientação na documentação do splancs.

No livro *Applied Spatial Data Analysis with R*, de Bivand, Pebesma e Gómez-Rubio (2013), tem um exemplo com o data set `Redwood` do `spatstats`:

```
library(spatstat)
data(redwood)
spred<-as(redwood, "SpatialPoints")

library(splancs)
mserwq <- mse2d(as.points(coordinates(spred)), as.points(list(x = c(0,
        + 1, 1, 0), y = c(0, 0, 1, 1))), 100, 0.15)
bwq <- mserwq$h[which.min(mserwq$mse)]
bwq
```

Esse exemplo funciona perfeitamente. Mas quando vou replicar esse script com meus dados retorna um erro. Vejam:

```
#Melocactus data
m23.Xs<-c(17349,13212,11551,16659,9461,12062,12802,9638,9835,9803)
m23.Ys<-c(576,13600,6372,11763,11081,5462,15802,11667,11552,11121)
loc23<-matrix(c(m23.Xs,m23.Ys),nrow=10,byrow=FALSE)
MSEm23<-mse2d(as.points(coodinates(loc.m23),as.points
        +(list(x=c(0,20000,20000,0),y=c(0,0,20000,20000))),100,0.15))

Erro em storage.mode(poly) <- "double" : 
  argumento "poly" ausente, sem padrão
```

Não consigo resolver esse erro. Já tentei especificar o polígono com um objeto "owin" e com matriz, e o mesmo erro continua. Alguém sabe como especificar um polígono no splancs?

Qualquer comentário de vocês será ótimo.
Agradeço por antecipação.

Abraços,
Leila

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leila, encontrei três problemas no seu código:

1. Você definiu a variável com o nome `loc23`, mas depois chama pelo nome `loc.m23`
2. Você chamou a função `coordinates` de `coodinates`, sem a letra `r`.
3. Há um erro de parênteses na sua *call* da função `mse2d()`. Veja que o segundo `as.points(...)` está dentro do primeiro, pois você só fechou um parêntese, de `coordinates`.

Resolvendo esses problemas, o código rodou e me deu um resultado parecido com o do exemplo, que você deve saber dizer se está correto.

```
library(splancs)
m23.Xs<-c(17349,13212,11551,16659,9461,12062,12802,9638,9835,9803)
m23.Ys<-c(576,13600,6372,11763,11081,5462,15802,11667,11552,11121)
loc23<-matrix(c(m23.Xs,m23.Ys),nrow=10,byrow=FALSE)
MSEm23<-mse2d(as.points(coordinates(loc23)),as.points(list(x=c(0,20000,20000,0),y=c(0,0,20000,20000))),100,0.15)

bwq2 <- MSEm23$h[which.min(MSEm23$mse)]
bwq2
[1] 0.15
```